# SAP UI5. Aggregation binding in JSON view. Works on 1.60 but doesn't in 1.80

Tags: json, data-binding, sapui5

I've been struggling with this issue and I was wondering if any of you would know what is going on here.

Working on a JSON view, which is basically a table with 1 column (working on a proof of concept). This column has to show a date so I use a DatePicker as a template and have a binding to my model. Looks like this:

```
{
"Type": "sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView",
"content": [
    {
        "Type": "sap.ui.table.Table",
        "id": "overviewTable",
        "selectionMode": "Single",
        "visibleRowCount": 3,
        "selectionBehavior": "RowOnly",
        "editable": false,
        "enableColumnReordering": false,
        "rows": {
            "path": "/items",
            "templateShareable": true
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "Type": "sap.ui.table.Column",
                "id": "MYPROPERTYID",
                "hAlign": "Left",
                "width": "100%",
                "resizable": false,
                "sortProperty": "MYPROPERTYID",
                "filterProperty": "MYPROPERTYID",
                "filterType": {
                    "type": "sap.ui.model.type.Date",
                    "formatOptions": {
                        "pattern": "MM/dd/yyyy"
                    }
                },
                "label": {
                    "Type": "sap.m.Label",
                    "text": "My property ID",
                    "design": "Bold"
                },
                "template": {
                    "Type": "sap.m.DatePicker",
                    "editable": false,
                    "value": {
                        "path": "MYPROPERTYID",
                        "type": "sap.ui.model.type.Date"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Running this app on 1.60 renders the table without problem. I have some dummy data in my backend (1 row of data basically) and it binds perfectly and shows the data as it should be.
On top of that, also have a set of other applications that follow the same Overview table on top, detail below format, with same kind of bindings and I never had an issue with this.
I've also noticed this is something specific to DatePicker. If I were to change my template to be an Input, for example, my aggregation binding would work.

[EDIT] The error I am getting is the following:
Loading of data failed: Error: "[object Object]" is not valid for aggregation "template" of Element sap.ui.table.Column

The error happens when trying to process this piece:

```
{
    "path": "MYPROPERTYID",
    "type": "sap.ui.model.type.Date"
}
```

My guess is that something has changed in between 1.60 and 1.71. This is as far as I have narrowed it down and I continue to investigate, I was just hoping maybe someone knows whats going on and can save me a few hours.

[EDIT] I have narrowed it down to somewhere between 1.63.1 and 1.64.1.
If you want to see this in action:
https://jsbin.com/medenuq/edit?html,console,output
Just play with the versions to see what happens.

Any idea would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticket, and you can track it here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2972

There codeworrior explains very well where the regression is coming from, and how to get around it until an official fix is released. I will just paste here his solution so that you dont have to go there if all you want is an answer:

```
"template": {
    "Type": "sap.m.DatePicker",
    **"ui5object": true,       // <-- marker property**
    "editable": false,
    "displayFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "valueFormat": "yyyyMMdd",
    "value": {
        "path": "Date",
        "type": "sap.ui.model.type.String"
    }
}
```

Thank you so much codeworrior for your quick help, and also thanks everyone who has looked at this and given it some thought.